# On the Weierstrass (AKA Kronecker form) of a Matrix Pencil

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

The question is as follows:

> Does the Weierstrass Canonical form (AKA Kronecker form) of a (linear) matrix pencil require the underlying field to be algebraically closed?

In this context, a (linear) matrix pencil is a matrix-valued function of the form 
$$
L(\lambda) := \lambda A + B
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of size $n$.  I am particularly interested in *regular* matrix pencils, i.e. those for which $\det L(\lambda)$ is not identically $0$.

I found a few references online, including [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379579900351) by Van Dooren, and I'm trying to understand it well enough to apply it to my particular issue.  However, I would appreciate it if somebody has a handy reference or quick argument about the underlying field.

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: @D.R. I gave up on it at the time, and I've forgotten a lot about the problem. However, looking at this anew, I have the impression that putting the pencil $\lambda I  + B$ into its canonical form is probably equivalent to putting $B$ in its Jordan form, which requires an algebraically closed field